# ROW to COLUMN in MySQL DataBase.

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

Consider an example of the following table:

[image: 2tables and a transistion table with a desired output at the right side]

*Please help me with all your knowledge, Thank you*
*I am considering of using only the database(MySQL) rite now. So if the output is shown, not using any PHP or java languages.*

Comment: Have a look at `SQL UNION Operator` http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Search for _pivot tables_ and _MySQL_ (This has nothing to do with UNIONS. Anytime you want to take the value of a column (such as Subject_Name) and make those values the columns - it is a a pivot table. UNIONs are used to append rows from one SQL statement to another)

Comment: Thank U @AgRizzo: It was much of a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I'm try to get exact solution as following as:***

```
SELECT two.stname,
SUM(smark*(1-ABS(SIGN(sname)))) AS en,
SUM(smark*(1-ABS(SIGN(sname)))) AS mat,
SUM(smark*(1-ABS(SIGN(sname)))) AS phy
FROM a1 AS ONE
LEFT JOIN a2 AS two
ON one.sid=two.stid
GROUP BY sname;
```

*the [**sqlfiddle to click**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5525aa/2)*